# The OnSubmit function isnt updating the react hook state variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, onsubmit

Here I am trying to create a recipe app that fetches its data from site called **Edamam**.
I am using React UseEffect to re-render my page everytime the user clicks on submit button.
i.e. The page will re render when *query* is upadated.

**CREATION OF STATES AND USEEFFECT**

```
const[recipes,setRecipes]=useState([]);
const[search,setSearch]=useState("");
const[query,setQuery]=useState('chicken');
 useEffect(()=>{
    getRecipes();
 },[query]);
```

**FETCHING DATA FROM API**

```
const getRecipes = async () => {
 const response=await fetch(
  `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    );
  const data= await response.json();
   setRecipes(data.hits);
   console.log(data.hits);
};
```

**EVENT HANDLER FUNCTIONS**

```
const UpdateSearch= (e) =>{
 setSearch(e.target.value);
}

const GetSearch= (e) =>{
  e.preventDefaut();
  setQuery(search);
  setSearch("");
};
```

**THE JSX PART**

```
return(
    <div className="App">
     <form onSubmit={GetSearch} className="search-form">
      <input
       type="text" 
       className="search-bar" 
       value={search} 
       onChange={UpdateSearch}/>
      <button  type="submit" className="search-button" > Search </button>
     </form>
     {query}
     {recipes.map(recipe=>(
       <Recipe/> // a different component
     ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does it work if you move the `getRecipes` function to inside of the `useEffect`?

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace `e.preventDefaut()` with `e.preventDefault()`